# Integral form of this IVP

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

How do I show that the following initial value problem
$$
xu''+u'+xu=0,\quad  u(0)=1,\quad u'(0)=0
$$
has the following integral form:
$$
u(x)=1+\int_{0}^{x} t\ln(t/x)u(t)\,dt
$$
I am stuck because if I divide both sides of both ODE by $x$
$$
u'+\frac{1}{x}u+u=0
$$
$\frac{1}{x}$ is undefined at $0$.

Comment: I've removed the [tag:mathematical-physics] and [tag:calculus-of-variations] tags because, while that may be where the problem came from, it is really just a question about differential/integral equations.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** From $$u(x)=1+\int_{0}^{x} t\ln(t/x)u(t)\,dt,$$ calculate $u'(x)$ and $u''(x)$ and show that this satisfies $xu''+u'+xu=0$.  Also show that $u(0) = 1$ and $u'(0) = 0$ (using L'Hopital's rule, if necessary).

Comment: After first differentiation I am led to $u'(x)=\int_{0}^{x}t\,u(t)\,dt\cdot -\frac{1}{x}\,dx$ and after second one I get $xu''(x)+xu=\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}tu(t)\,dt$. I can't show the RHS is the same as $u'(x)$